# How to detect an android phone contacts app supports Structured Postal Address?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

Samsung galaxy S4 and some devices are only supporting Structured postal while using **Intent Action_Insert**

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
...
ContentValues name = new ContentValues();
name.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
name.put(StructuredPostal.STREET, bundle.getString(StructuredPostal.STREET));
name.put(StructuredPostal.CITY, bundle.getString(StructuredPostal.CITY));
name.put(StructuredPostal.REGION, bundle.getString(StructuredPostal.REGION));
name.put(StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD, bundle.getString(StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD));
name.put(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, bundle.getString(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
name.put(StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, bundle.getString(StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
data.add(name);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, contactName);

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);
else
  intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, address);
```

Now for Galaxy S3 which runs on 4.2 doesn't support Structured Address and not showing the address using the above code.

So How do I find if a device supports structured postal address so that I can provide support for both?

**Note:** If I use `intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, address);` Galaxy S3 shows the address where as while using `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);` this S3 not able to show the address.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving both the structured fields as you do (for phones that support them) as well as the `StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS`. You'll need to do the formatting yourself, though. That's what [VCardEntry](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/vcard/+/5a708740cf128604d53da3fcf6d0ad92dd913f98/java/com/android/vcard/VCardEntry.java) does, it seems.